# DREAM: ManPy simple server example not working

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am trying to run the ManPy simulation engine. I installed all the dependencies and installed the DREAM module. Now I am trying to run the simple server example from the ManPy website (http://www.manpy-simulation.org):

```
from dream.simulation.imports import Source, Queue, Machine, Exit  
from dream.simulation.Globals import runSimulation

#define the objects of the model 
S=Source('S1','Source',interarrivalTime={'distributionType':'Fixed','mean':0.5}, entity='Dream.Part')
Q=Queue('Q1','Queue', capacity=1)
M=Machine('M1','Machine', processingTime={'distributionType':'Fixed','mean':0.25})
E=Exit('E1','Exit')  

#define predecessors and successors for the objects    
S.defineRouting(successorList=[Q])
Q.defineRouting(predecessorList=[S],successorList=[M])
M.defineRouting(predecessorList=[Q],successorList=[E])
E.defineRouting(predecessorList=[M])

# call the runSimulation giving the objects and the length of the experiment
runSimulation(objectList=[S,Q,M,E], maxSimTime=1440.0)

# calculate metrics
working_ratio = (M.totalWorkingTime/1440.0)*100 

#print the results
print "the system produced", E.numOfExits, "parts"
print "the total working ratio of the Machine is", working_ratio, "%"'
```

The expected result, according to the website is

> the system produced 2880 parts
>
> the total working ratio of the Machine is 50.0 %

But opposed to this, when I execute the script I receive the statement:

> the system produced 1440 parts
>
> the total working ratio of the Machine is 0.0 %

The number of produced parts is simply the maximum simulation time in seconds.

Any suggestions or anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the fact that ManPy API was updated in order to declare distributions more flexibly. The documentation in the website (I suppose http://www.manpy-simulation.org/ ?), was never updated, and indeed the plan is to be done more examples (see the PDF I link below) when time is found.

The correct code of this example is here:
https://lab.nexedi.com/nexedi/dream/blob/master/dream/simulation/Examples/SingleServer.py

So not:

`processingTime={'distributionType':'Fixed','mean':0.25}`

but:
`processingTime={'Fixed':{'mean':0.25}}`

Generally, we give the distribution type as key of the outer dict and all parameters in an inner dict.

An updated version of the documentation (sadly still in PDF and not yet in an html version) is here:
https://lab.nexedi.com/nexedi/dream/blob/master/ManPy_documentation.pdf. This contains more examples.

Please inform if this does not work